# R dynamic brownian bridge movement model raster error

Tags: r

To explore my data (presence/absence data at certain locations) I wish to model Utilization distributions using dynamic brownian bridge movement models (dBBMM) using the "move" package. I'm trying to figure out how it works and so I created a simple code to run a dBBMM for subsets of my data in order to create some plots. It seems that the same specification of coding works for 1 subset, but not for the other. Specifically, I get the error returned

```
Error in .local(object, raster, location.error, ext, ...) : 
  Lower x grid not large enough
```

This is one subset of the data:

```
data.ss1<-structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1455851760, 1455851880, 
1455852000, 1455852180, 1455857220, 1455857340, 1455915720, 1455915780, 
1455916020, 1455917760, 1455918240, 1455920100, 1455920520, 1455920700, 
1455920940, 1455921060, 1456786200, 1456786620, 1456788960, 1456789080, 
1456789200, 1456821540, 1456821660, 1456821960, 1457295480, 1457295600, 
1457296260, 1457296380, 1457296500, 1457296800, 1457319240, 1457319540, 
1457319660, 1457319780, 1457322900, 1457323020, 1457323140, 1457323320, 
1457323440, 1457325000, 1457325180, 1457325420, 1457325600, 1457325720, 
1457326560, 1457326680, 1457333340, 1457333700, 1457333820, 1457334000, 
1457334120, 1457334240, 1457334360, 1457353800, 1457353920, 1457354040, 
1457354280, 1457354400, 1457354700, 1457355780, 1457355960, 1457356080, 
1457356200, 1457356320, 1457364600, 1457364780, 1457365020, 1457365320, 
1457365500, 1457365620, 1457365740, 1457365860, 1457365980, 1457366100, 
1457366220, 1457407200, 1457407380, 1457407500, 1457407560, 1457407680, 
1457407800, 1457407920, 1457408040, 1457408160, 1457408280, 1457408340, 
1457408580, 1457408700, 1457408820, 1457408940, 1457409060, 1457409480, 
1457409600, 1457409780, 1457409900, 1457410320, 1457412540, 1457412660, 
1457412780, 1457412900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "US/Eastern"), 
    station = c(109655L, 109655L, 109655L, 109655L, 124083L, 
    124083L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126412L, 126412L, 126413L, 
    126413L, 126413L, 126413L, 126413L, 102307L, 102307L, 126413L, 
    126413L, 126413L, 126407L, 126407L, 126407L, 124086L, 124086L, 
    124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 104668L, 104668L, 104668L, 
    104668L, 126408L, 126408L, 126408L, 126408L, 126408L, 126410L, 
    126410L, 126410L, 126410L, 126410L, 126410L, 126410L, 104668L, 
    104668L, 104668L, 104668L, 104668L, 104668L, 104668L, 124086L, 
    124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 
    124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 
    124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 
    124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 
    124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 
    124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 
    124086L, 124086L, 124086L, 124086L), elasmo = structure(c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("7954", "19681", 
    "19690", "19691", "20180", "20182", "20184", "23156", "23794", 
    "23796", "27549", "27551"), class = "factor"), location = c("pier", 
    "pier", "pier", "pier", "new barge", "new barge", "bimini barge", 
    "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "west west round rock", "west west round rock", 
    "west north west turtle", "west north west turtle", "west north west turtle", 
    "west north west turtle", "west north west turtle", "south west south turtle", 
    "south west south turtle", "west north west turtle", "west north west turtle", 
    "west north west turtle", "mini wall", "mini wall", "mini wall", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "west round rock", "west round rock", "west round rock", 
    "west round rock", "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", 
    "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", 
    "west turtle", "west turtle", "west turtle", "west turtle", 
    "west turtle", "west turtle", "west turtle", "west round rock", 
    "west round rock", "west round rock", "west round rock", 
    "west round rock", "west round rock", "west round rock", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west", "mini barge west", 
    "mini barge west", "mini barge west"), Y = c(25.76453, 25.76453, 
    25.76453, 25.76453, 25.74273, 25.74273, 25.69792, 25.69792, 
    25.69792, 25.68681, 25.68681, 25.67408, 25.67408, 25.67408, 
    25.67408, 25.67408, 25.65654, 25.65654, 25.67408, 25.67408, 
    25.67408, 25.81482, 25.81482, 25.81482, 25.72441, 25.72441, 
    25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.68646, 25.68646, 
    25.68646, 25.68646, 25.67416, 25.67416, 25.67416, 25.67416, 
    25.67416, 25.66495, 25.66495, 25.66495, 25.66495, 25.66495, 
    25.66495, 25.66495, 25.68646, 25.68646, 25.68646, 25.68646, 
    25.68646, 25.68646, 25.68646, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 
    25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 
    25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 
    25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 
    25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 
    25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 
    25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 
    25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 25.72441, 
    25.72441, 25.72441), X = c(-79.29315, -79.29315, -79.29315, 
    -79.29315, -79.30235, -79.30235, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, 
    -79.32016, -79.32016, -79.31871, -79.31871, -79.31871, -79.31871, 
    -79.31871, -79.3227, -79.3227, -79.31871, -79.31871, -79.31871, 
    -79.28847, -79.28847, -79.28847, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, 
    -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.31012, -79.31012, -79.31012, 
    -79.31012, -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.30888, 
    -79.31092, -79.31092, -79.31092, -79.31092, -79.31092, -79.31092, 
    -79.31092, -79.31012, -79.31012, -79.31012, -79.31012, -79.31012, 
    -79.31012, -79.31012, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, 
    -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, 
    -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, 
    -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, 
    -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, 
    -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, 
    -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, 
    -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, -79.30922, 
    -79.30922)), .Names = c("timestamp", "station", "elasmo", 
"location", "Y", "X"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is a second:

```
data.ss2<-structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1414786140, 1414786740, 
1420747380, 1420750020, 1425956580, 1425956940, 1427796900, 1427797080, 
1453615800, 1453616040, 1453616400, 1453618020, 1453618920, 1453619580, 
1453619760, 1460017140, 1460017680, 1460017860, 1460141880, 1460142060, 
1460144040, 1460145300, 1460181840, 1460183100, 1460215860, 1460216100, 
1460378040, 1460378760, 1460403840, 1460404140, 1460456100, 1460456280, 
1460456460, 1460540340, 1460541600, 1460863560, 1460864160, 1460875860, 
1460876880, 1460882040, 1460883960, 1460887200, 1460887740, 1460928540, 
1460929200, 1460948160, 1460948340, 1460953920, 1460954220, 1461037440, 
1461038100, 1461041220, 1461041400, 1461041580, 1461043320, 1461043500, 
1461046260, 1461046440, 1461059340, 1461059700, 1461059820, 1461060000, 
1461060720, 1461061440, 1461061860, 1461062100, 1461062700, 1461062880, 
1461063060, 1461063240, 1461063420, 1461064140, 1461064320, 1461064500, 
1461064800, 1461065160, 1461065340, 1461065880, 1461066780, 1461066960, 
1461072060, 1461072300, 1461072900, 1461073080, 1461119580, 1461120240, 
1461124320, 1461124500, 1461124620, 1461166500, 1461166680, 1461166920, 
1461167100, 1461216840, 1461217560, 1461218880, 1461219060, 1461219660, 
1461219840, 1461221280), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "US/Eastern"), 
    station = c(104667L, 104667L, 124097L, 124097L, 125904L, 
    125904L, 125907L, 125907L, 126408L, 126408L, 126408L, 126410L, 
    126410L, 126411L, 126411L, 126406L, 126406L, 126406L, 125906L, 
    125906L, 125906L, 125906L, 125904L, 126406L, 125904L, 125904L, 
    106809L, 106809L, 125906L, 125906L, 126408L, 126408L, 126408L, 
    126408L, 126408L, 126408L, 126408L, 126410L, 126410L, 126408L, 
    126408L, 126411L, 126411L, 104668L, 104668L, 104668L, 104668L, 
    126411L, 126411L, 104668L, 104668L, 126410L, 126410L, 126410L, 
    126411L, 126411L, 126411L, 126411L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 
    126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 
    126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 
    126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 126404L, 
    126404L, 126404L, 104668L, 104668L, 126410L, 126410L, 126410L, 
    126408L, 126408L, 126408L, 126408L, 126413L, 126413L, 104668L, 
    104668L, 104668L, 104668L, 126408L), elasmo = structure(c(11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("7954", "19681", "19690", "19691", 
    "20180", "20182", "20184", "23156", "23794", "23796", "27549", 
    "27551"), class = "factor"), location = c("bimini barge", 
    "bimini barge", "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", 
    "west turtle", "west turtle", "west west round rock", "west west round rock", 
    "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", 
    "west turtle", "west turtle", "south west turtle", "south west turtle", 
    "south bimini 3", "south bimini 3", "south bimini 3", "south bimini 1", 
    "south bimini 1", "south bimini 1", "south bimini 1", "south bimini 3 south", 
    "south bimini 3", "south bimini 3 south", "south bimini 3 south", 
    "south bimini 1 south", "south bimini 1 south", "south bimini 1", 
    "south bimini 1", "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", 
    "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", 
    "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", "west turtle", 
    "west turtle", "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", 
    "south west turtle", "south west turtle", "west round rock", 
    "west round rock", "west round rock", "west round rock", 
    "south west turtle", "south west turtle", "west round rock", 
    "west round rock", "west turtle", "west turtle", "west turtle", 
    "south west turtle", "south west turtle", "south west turtle", 
    "south west turtle", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", 
    "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", 
    "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", 
    "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", 
    "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", 
    "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", 
    "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "bimini barge", "west round rock", 
    "west round rock", "west turtle", "west turtle", "west turtle", 
    "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", "northwest turtle rock", 
    "northwest turtle rock", "west north west turtle", "west north west turtle", 
    "west round rock", "west round rock", "west round rock", 
    "west round rock", "northwest turtle rock"), Y = c(25.69792, 
    25.69792, 25.67416, 25.67416, 25.66495, 25.66495, 25.68681, 
    25.68681, 25.67416, 25.67416, 25.67416, 25.66495, 25.66495, 
    25.65662, 25.65662, 25.68256, 25.68256, 25.68256, 25.68266, 
    25.68266, 25.68266, 25.68266, 25.67332, 25.68256, 25.67332, 
    25.67332, 25.67316, 25.67316, 25.68266, 25.68266, 25.67416, 
    25.67416, 25.67416, 25.67416, 25.67416, 25.67416, 25.67416, 
    25.66495, 25.66495, 25.67416, 25.67416, 25.65662, 25.65662, 
    25.68646, 25.68646, 25.68646, 25.68646, 25.65662, 25.65662, 
    25.68646, 25.68646, 25.66495, 25.66495, 25.66495, 25.65662, 
    25.65662, 25.65662, 25.65662, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 
    25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 
    25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 
    25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 
    25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.69792, 25.68646, 
    25.68646, 25.66495, 25.66495, 25.66495, 25.67416, 25.67416, 
    25.67416, 25.67416, 25.67408, 25.67408, 25.68646, 25.68646, 
    25.68646, 25.68646, 25.67416), X = c(-79.31699, -79.31699, 
    -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.31092, -79.31092, -79.32016, -79.32016, 
    -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.31092, -79.31092, -79.31325, 
    -79.31325, -79.2818, -79.2818, -79.2818, -79.30135, -79.30135, 
    -79.30135, -79.30135, -79.28196, -79.2818, -79.28196, -79.28196, 
    -79.30154, -79.30154, -79.30135, -79.30135, -79.30888, -79.30888, 
    -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.31092, 
    -79.31092, -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.31325, -79.31325, -79.31012, 
    -79.31012, -79.31012, -79.31012, -79.31325, -79.31325, -79.31012, 
    -79.31012, -79.31092, -79.31092, -79.31092, -79.31325, -79.31325, 
    -79.31325, -79.31325, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, 
    -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, 
    -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, 
    -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, 
    -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31699, -79.31012, -79.31012, 
    -79.31092, -79.31092, -79.31092, -79.30888, -79.30888, -79.30888, 
    -79.30888, -79.31871, -79.31871, -79.31012, -79.31012, -79.31012, 
    -79.31012, -79.30888)), .Names = c("timestamp", "station", 
"elasmo", "location", "Y", "X"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

My issue is that I don't really know how to set the raster parameter in combination with the extension parameter. It returns an error for 1 data set given a specified model, but not the other. These are just 2 mini subsets of larger individual data sets and I have >100 individuals. So it would be useful if I can specify a model that can accommodate all datasets to the best of its ability. I guess I can set the `ext` parameter to a large number for all of my models, but am unsure if this is ideal and best approach. Thank you for any help!

This is the R code I'm using for the subsets:

```
    require(move)

ss1 <- move(x=data.ss1$X, y=data.ss1$Y, time=as.POSIXct(data.ss1$timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="US/Eastern"), 
            proj=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"),data=data.ss1, animal="20186") 

data.sAEQD1 <- spTransform(ss1, center=T)

x_UD1 <- brownian.bridge.dyn(data.sAEQD1, window.size=31, ext=1.5,
                             margin=15, raster=100,
                             location.error=23)
ss2 <- move(x=data.ss2$X, y=data.ss2$Y, time=as.POSIXct(data.ss2$timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="US/Eastern"), 
            proj=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"),data=data.ss2, animal="27549") 

data.sAEQD2 <- spTransform(ss2, center=T)

x_UD2 <- brownian.bridge.dyn(data.sAEQD2, window.size=31, ext=1.5,
                             margin=15, raster=100,
                             location.error=23)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few remarks, first of all since the 2.0 version of the move package setting a large extent (ext) does not go at the cost of long computation times so setting a somewhat higher number such as 2 or 3 does not hurt.

The raster argument sets the resolution of the grid used for UD calculations. This has a major influence on the calculation time. If the resolution twice as large calculations should be 4 times faster.

The ext argument determines how much the raster is extended beyond the extent of the trajectory.

Given it is data from recording stations it is especially important to check the model results because long periods of stationarity might lead to very small sigma estimates. I also notices you sometimes have rather long intervals between recordings (10 days, alternated by 2 minute recordings) this generally causes the UD to stretch out quite wide because of the large uncertainty of where the animal is. It also causes recordings to be quite slow because a small time step is chosen for the numerical integration, setting time.step=.6 or so might speed things up (by default time.step is set to 1/15 of the shortest interval).